# How to Delete a Record from a csv file with arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, csv, export-to-csv, delete-row

I just want to know when you overwrite the elements for deleting a certain element , you change the position of all the elements after it.The thing is when you change the position the last element in the last element will be same as the second last. here in this code i am changing the last element to be empty which i don't want . I just want to  remove it so i can save it in csv. If i write null then it saves 'null' in csv as a record which i dont want! Please help!

```
 public static void deleteEntry() {
        int flag = -1;
        Boolean found = false;
        System.out.println("Please provide the name of the contact to delete its entry: ");
        String searchName2 = sc.next().toUpperCase();
        System.out.println(counter);
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
                if (names[i].compareTo(searchName2) == 0) {
                    flag = i;
                    found = true;

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        if (flag == -1) {
            System.out.println("Contact Name  NOT Found");
        } else { //record was found, flag is a positive index position
            //if the record is the last record, simply remove it and decrement the counter
            if (flag == counter - 1) {
                System.out.println("Contact Deleted!");
                names[flag] = null;
                numbers[flag] = null;
                counter--;
            }else {

                //record is not the last record, shift all later records down
                for (int i = flag; i < counter-1; i++){
                    names[i] = names[i + 1];
                    numbers[i] = numbers[i + 1];



                }
                System.out.println(counter);
                System.out.println("Contact Deleted!");
                if (names[counter-1].equals(names[counter-2])) {
                    names[counter-1] = "";
                    numbers[counter-1] = "";

                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using a Collection? It looks like you're keeping track of names and corresponding numbers, which would be much easier in a `Map<String, Integer>`. You could then just call `Map::remove` to remove an element from the map.

Comment: the thing is i know maps but we havent touched that topic yet i guess we are restricted with this limitation of arrays. . you are right about names and numbers. isnt there any way i could just delete the last row of the csv in java?

Comment: FYI: your question has nothing to do with CSV files, you just want to delete an item from an array, which isn't possible. What you could do is create a new array with size `n - 1` to replace the old array of size `n` and copy all elements **except** the one you want to delete to the new array. You could do this by manually looping over elements or by using `arrayCopy` twice (once for all elements up to the one you want to delete and once for all elements after).

Comment: the thing is the code was too big to understand what to do in csv. I got your point even i was suggested this explanation by someone else but the thing is .. i am making a program which depends on the user to when to delete and add an element to an array . and when to save those in a csv , so it would not be possible i suppose to save these new arrays .. it becomes complicated to even think about it ! :}